# iMac won't restart after upgrade to Yosemite

Tags: imac, macos

Just made the upgrade to Yosemite but now my iMac wont restart or shut down. Whenever I try to do any of these it stays on a black screen with a mouse pointer, and I have to turn it off and back on manually.

Any help?

Comment: Can you describe your problem with more details please? Are you inside Yosemite? And then you click on the Apple-Icon and Shut your Mac down? Which iMac do you have?

Comment: did you try any of the start ups like Safe mode....and you made a USB?

Comment: @miro  What is your System Model  ?

Answer (score 1):

Mine was showing a black screen after I updated my iMac to Yosemite.

I unplugged my USB mouse and the new Login screen was displayed.

No restart was necessary.